# How to show turning points for function on graph in Python?

Tags: python, derivative

The requirement is to **define this function `f(x) = x^3 - 15x^2 - 18x + 1` and then plot it in such a way that the plotting region shows all of the turning points.**

I think that my calculations below are wrong because if you look at the graph there are at least 2 turning points.
By that I mean that the function is first increasing and then is decreasing, but in my calculation I found a single solution for `x`, where `x = 0.5`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})

#1. define the function
def f(x): 
    return x**3 - 15*x**2 - 18*x + 1


#find the turning points of a polynomial of 3rd degree

#2. find the derivative of  x**3 - 15*x**2 - 18*x + 1 
# the derivative is -15(2x + 1)

#3. by the null factor law, get the value of x: 
# 2x + 1 = 0
# 2x = 1
# x = 0.5

#4. check what is f(x) for x = 0.5
0.5**3 - 15*0.5**2 - 18*0.5 + 1 = -39/4 = -9.75

#5. Therefore, we can conclude that there is a single turning point at A(0.5, -9.75)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.plot(0.5,f(0.5),'.r', ms=20,label='x_1') #plot A(0.5, -9.75)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT_1**

Based on Picarus suggestion, I have recalculated the derivative, but the solution of my equation don't look as correct on the graph.

```
def f(x): 
    return x**3 - 15*x**2 - 18*x + 1


#find the turning points of a polynomial of 3rd degree

#2. find the derivative of  x**3 - 15*x**2 - 18*x + 1 
# Workout the derivative
# (x**3)' = 3*x**2
# (-15*x**2)' = -30*x
# (-18x)' = -18
# (1)' = 0 
# Therefore our derviative equation is 3*x**2 -30*x  -18
#Bring it to a more concise form
# 3(x**2 - 10*x -6) = 0

#Find the x solution for x**2 - 10*x -6 
#Delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
#x1 = (10 + sqr(76))/2  = 9.358
#x2 = (10 - sqr(76))/2  = -3.84


x1 = (10 + np.sqrt(76))/2
x2 = (10 - np.sqrt(76))/2
print(x1)
print(x2)

#4. check what is f(x) for:  x1 = 9.358, x2 = 0.641

x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.plot(x1,f(x1),'.r', ms=20,label='x_1') 
plt.plot(x2,f(x2),'.b', ms=20,label='x_2') 
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The derivative of a 3rd degree polynomial  is a 2nd degree polynomial. In particular your derivative is 3*x**2-30*x-18

Comment: Ok, so we could say that the solution for the  derivative is ```3(x**2 - 10x - 6)```. How do I factor this quadratic so I can get the values of ```x```?

Comment: If I don't know how to factor ```3(x**2 - 10x - 6)```. I  can try to find Delta and solutions for x1, 2. ```D = b**2 - 4*a*c```. Therefore ```D = 100 - 24 = 76```. And ```x1,x2 = (-b +- sqr(D))/2*a```. Now, ```x1 = (10 + sqr(76) ) / 2``` and ```x2 =  (10 - sqr(76) ) / 2```. Is this correct?

Comment: @Picarus I've edited my question and implemented based on your answer. Could you you please advise?

Comment: The maths seem correct,  but your plot is wrong. X2  is not plotted in the right place. Also increase your linspace interval so you can see the whole relevant are, do something like -10 to 20. Your blue and red dot must be at the top or bottom of the plot, they are local maxims or minima. I am answering from my tablet so can't be more specific.

Comment: And the function you are plotting is also incorrect, see this tool for how the plot should look.https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/grapher-equation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# generate some toy data
n = 600
t = np.linspace(0, 600, n)
y = (300 * np.exp(-0.1 * t) + 1) + 20 * (np.random.random(n))

# get the gradient
dy = np.gradient(y)

# search gradient for first occurrence of thresh value:
thresh = 0.01
idx_thresh = np.argmax(dy > thresh)
# y[idx_thresh] would be the "turning point"

# visualization
plt.plot(t, y, 'b', label='y')
plt.plot(t, dy, 'g', label='dy')
plt.plot(t[idx_thresh:], y[idx_thresh:], 'r', label=f'y[dy > {thresh}]')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: I have to resolve this without using built in methods such as ```np.gradient```. It is more focused on working out the math problem manually and representing it with the help of python. I have run your code and it plots more than 2 points on the graph https://imgur.com/OeDZG7P